# VIM: More precise C/C++ code parsing solutions?

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

**Pre:**
I've been working in VIM for like a year already. Lots of great things: combinations, scripts. Whenever I'm editing something in a different editor, I feel sluggish/uncomfortable without VIM's navigation.

**The problem:**
The thing that really bothers me most of all is source code navigation using existing tools (ctags, cscope). Often, ctags can't find the declaration of a variable, cscope as opposed to ctags finds all definitions with the same variable name. Same craziness with call tree navigation, finding forward declarations along with a single class definition etc.
Compared to MS Intellisense, Visual Assist or even source code navigation in Eclipse, Exuberant Tags/cscope seems to be deprecated for at least 10 years.

I know there are tools like ViEMU, but they don't really solve the problem, since you lose lots of VIM's functionality.

**The question:**
I was wondering if there is a tool that does the source parsing better, or there is some way to integrate source parsing engines like Intellisense into VIM ?
Maybe there are commercial solutions or there are people who are ready to implement one ?

All the benefits of VIM seem to save less time than is being wasted while navigating to class definition, compared to Visual Assist, where it's done by a single Alt-G shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

### Search and Call tree

You could try [eclim](http://eclim.org/), which is a way to use some Eclipse features in Vim.

For C/C++, it provides :

- Context sensitive completion (although it is disabled on Windows because it is buggy)
- Context sensitive search in Project files (through `:CSearchContext`)
- Call tree for functions/methods (`:CCallHierarchy`)
- Code Validation (`:Validate`)

It is not great, but it can help in some cases.

### Code Completion

Regarding automatic code completion, I primarily use [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520), which is using tags to provide Context aware code completion. It is not that bad.

As advised by Luc Hermitte, you can also use [clang_complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302) which does not need ctags, but needs clang installed.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte : Thanks for the suggestion, I will try clang_complete

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, it is a real problem. ctags or cscope can hardly compete with Visual Studio code browsing - it actually uses a C++ compiler front-end to parse the code for the editor.