# precise member function navigation through ctags

Tags: vim, ctags

The problem of using ctags in vim is that when I hit "SomeClass::SomeStaticFunc" or "SomeClass.someFunc" by "C-]", it lists many options, as someFunc may be the name of several member functions of different classes. How can I get more precise information? Can ctags be context aware?

BTW, I used ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .to generate the tags file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ctags can't be context aware (it uses a flat file and a simple heuristic), but you can use `:tn` and `:tp` to move through the tag stack to find the appropriate definition.

Comment: I have `:tp` and `:tn` mapped as such: `nnoremap [t :tp<cr>` and `nnoremap ]t :tn<cr>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520).

Also see this SO post:  [ctags ignore lists for libc6, libstdc++ and boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626188/ctags-ignore-lists-for-libc6-libstdc-and-boost)

Also take a look at [clang_complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302).  See this SO post:

[VIM: More precise C/C++ code parsing solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080211/vim-more-precise-c-c-code-parsing-solutions)